# How to access web gui via dyndns?

Tags: networking, transmission, dyndns

### What I want

I want to have access to managing my Bittorent sync and Transmission applications from the outside of my home network.

### My system and network

I have Xubuntu 13.04 on my laptop connected to router via WiFi.

### What I've done

Sine I don't have a static IP, I've registered an account and domain on [no-ip](http://www.noip.com/), installed their application and followed the manual to configure. Then I turned on web access to btsync and transmission and did port forwarding on my router.

The thing is I don't get how can I finally use it. E.g. I access my btsync from the laptop, where it runs via `my_laptop_ip:8888/gui`. How can I do that from the outside my network? If I try `my_noip_domain:8888/gui`, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You must use NAT or port forwarding on your router.

You Transmission server have a private address inside your network.  You web company delivers your a Internet Adress for your house.  Those are of course distinct, internal address do not touch the Internet addresses, except for outgoing traffic, and some exception as peer-to-peer file sharing.

You should connect the port 8888 from the outside Internet to your port 8888 of your's server internal IP Address.  That is called port forwarding or NAT.  The way of doing this depends on the web router you have.

Try tape "myroutermodel NAT howto" in a search engine of the Internet.

Hope it is helpfull

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did try to set-up port-forwarding on my router. Actually I used 2 different routers with different ISPs, but with no luck. It seems to me, that the issue is on the ISP side.

Comment: No, that is not possible : ISP cannot block ports across Europe.  Some evil guys try up to make it possible to restrain web access to some port or even some websites.  But, no ISP is behaving so bad for the moment!  Make sure you have the same configuration for both routers.  You may test openess of your port in the transmission-gtk interface (use "ssh -y (...)") for using it once...

Comment: nether the less, the answer is rather useless as I have clearly stated, that I have set up port forwarding. no offence